# Can't download previously purchased app

Tags: ios-appstore

I need to download an app from the iTunes store and have recently changed my Apple ID. I previously purchased this app with my old account and when I try to re-download it the iCloud symbol is the only option available. When I click on the iCloud icon, however, I cannot download it.

Comment: what do you mean with `i changed my Apple ID`

Comment: Can you add a screenshot for clarity? (Command-Shift-4, spacebar, select and click)

Answer (score 1):

If as you say, you changed the Apple ID, the stuff from previous Apple ID is NOT accessible with new ID.

To get there you must use old Apple ID.

Answer (score 0):

When you've bought an app on your ID then delete and then changed the apple ID and try to download it with another ID you can't get it because you bought it on the other ID so you have to download it on your old Apple ID.

Answer (score -1):

If by `iCloud icon`, you mean this:

[image]

This is the icon that indicates that you have purchased this app already. Tapping on it will download the app.

Comment: "when I try to re-download it the iCloud symbol is the only option available. When I click on the iCloud icon, however, I cannot download it."